# The nuances of the limiting modifier "only ever"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have heard and seen "only ever" used to put emphasis on "only". But in the following sentence I feel it's the other way and it is used to put emphasis on "ever".

"Maps are only ever partial; not only are they out of date as soon as they are made, but they are also never the same scale as the territory."

Am I correct?
If yes please elaborate on the case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the unmarked version would be "Maps are () ever partial"?

Comment: Where did you get the sentence from, please? It doesn't sound very idiomatic. I find 'Maps never give the complete picture ...' or 'No map can ever be accurate down to the last detail ...' more satisfactory. But with 'Explanations of fundamental particles are only ever partial', omitting 'only' leaves a very literary form totally off-register / omitting 'ever' is fine, but lacks the emphasis you rightly see 'ever' affords, and sounds a little distant even for formal writing.

Comment: The sentence is drawn from an academic book, so I guess it can't be wrong. I can name the book if it's not against the rules.

Comment: @Lawrence you are correct, that is what I feel the text is about to say.

Comment: If it's a quote, it's against 'the rules' (including Copyright Law) _not_ to link and attribute. // I'd certainly try to express 'maps are only ever partial' in a more appropriate way. Do they miss the odd town out?

Comment: Giving the source of a quotation is not against the rules. I'm not sure what you mean by 'putting the emphasis on _ever_'. Surely it means 'Maps are always only partial'?

Comment: @Kate-Bunting looking at the rest of the sentence implies that the writer is trying to give evidence for the maps being partial in different times, so it shows that there is no emphasis on "only" but on "ever".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry but I don't get what "Do they miss the odd town out?" is to say.

Comment: How is this different from other uses of 'only ever'? 'Ever' implies 'always' or 'at any time'.  'I only ever eat turkey at Christmas' = every year, Christmas is the only time I eat turkey.

Comment: 'Maps are partial' sounds pretty unidiomatic to me. 'Maps only give partial coverage'' is possible, but my previous two suggestions give what is probably the intended sense. // Ah, I've checked on the internet. There are quite a few hits, but using the 'biased / prejudiced' sense, not the 'incomplete' sense spelled out here. Putting England at the centre, say.

Comment: @KateBunting The difference is about is it to say "I only eat turkey at Christmas" or "I always eat turkey at Christmas"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you saying it's all about American or British English?

Comment: My point was that I don't see any difference between 'Maps are only ever partial' and 'I only ever eat turkey at Christmas'.

Comment: No; I'm saying that 'Maps are only ever partial/biased; not only are they out of date as soon as they are made, but they are also never the same scale as the territory.' is disjoint, while  'Maps are only ever partial/incomplete; not only are they out of date as soon as they are made, but they are also never the same scale as the territory.' is a very unusual usage of the 'only a part' sense of 'partial'. // 'An academic book "can't" be wrong'? Read [Bill Hazelton on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-common-to-find-mistakes-in-textbooks). **You still need to identify your source.**

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The source is "Skills in Existential Counselling & Psychotherapy" By Emmy van Deurzen and Martin Adams, P3.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth By the way thank you very much for the link you provided, it was wonderful.